# What are the consequences of removing the header image in a WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on my first WordPress theme.

The client doesn't seem to want a header image on every page, so I was just going to remove the `<img>` tag for the header image, but I want to double check first, what kind of impact will that have?

For example, does it affect certain widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the theme was coded.  Generally it shouldn't have any effect but removing the  tag could shift some of the other elements.

Create a backup first and then try it.  if something goes wrong you can replace the backup.